# SQL query to exclude records that already mapped with another column id and show rest to them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to achieve the following but not able to

```
Id   CatID  CategoryName
-------------------------
1    1      Movies
2    1      Movies
3    2      Books
4    3      Tools
```

What I am trying to achieve is :

I want all the records :

1. not having ID as 1 and
2. Exclude (CatID) records that ID = 1 is sharing with other IDs. In this case Id =1 and Id = 2 sharing the same CATID= 1 (Movies). I want to eliminate such records and show the rest of them.

Output :

```
Id   CatID  CategoryName
-------------------------
3    2      Books
4    3      Tools
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.catID = t.catID and t1.id = 1
)
```

For performance with this query, consider an index on `(catID, id)`.